# using ON UPDATE for non-timestamp columns

Tags: mariadb

Timestamp columns may have `DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE NOW()` which is awesome to keep track of when the row was updated.

I want to have similar functionality with user id, such that when an `update` statement is executed with `last_user_id = 42` then the value 42 is stored. But when the `update` statement is missing the assignment of `last_user_id` it is automatically reset to `NULL`, to indicate that the last modification to the row has happened in a context without any user.

Is it possible to use `DEFAULT ON UPDATE` for non-timestamp columns? If not, is it possible to achieve this behavior with triggers?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, triggers are the perfect candidate.  Something like this.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE UPDATE
ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
IF old.last_user_id = new.last_user_id THEN
   set new.last_user_id = null;
END IF;
```

The `old.` and `new.` values are available for updates.  So it checks if last_user_id has changed, and if not, sets it to null.

The only **problem** is that if the same user updates it, `last_user_id` will get set to null.  The way to get around this is to have another sacrificial field say `by_user` (tinyint) that is set to 0 or 1 to indicate how it's being updated.  And you never have to store its value, which will mean no extra storage

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE UPDATE
ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
IF new.by_user = 0 THEN
   set new.last_user_id = null;
END IF;
set new.by_user = null;
```

To clarify, the new field is always being stored as null, so has minimal impact on database size.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference between user_id and last_user_id?

Comment: @Tomas -  Oops, I answered it the way I had it set up on my DBs in the past, assuming you had a column called user_id.  I have corrected it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Comparing old and new for equality is a neat trick. Unfortunately, this will fail if the same user updates the same row multiple times with same `last_user_id`, which erroneously stores NULL.

Comment: Yes it will fail, I should have added that caveat.